# Parse a plain text into a Java Object

Tags: java, parsing, plaintext

I´m parsing a plain text and trying to convert into an Object.

The text looks like(and i can´t change the format):

```
"N001";"2014-08-12-07.11.37.352000";"         ";"some@email.com        ";4847       ;"street";"NAME        SURNAME                 ";26  ;"CALIFORNIA                      ";21
```

and The Object to convert:

```
String index;
String timestamp;
String mail;
Integer zipCode
...
```

I´ve tried with:

```
 StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(N001\";\"2014-08-12-07.11.37.352000\";\"         \";\"some@email.com        \";4847       ;\"street\";\"NAME        SURNAME                 \";26  ;\"CALIFORNIA                      \";21);

 while(st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
          System.out.println(st2.nextToken(";").replaceAll("\"",""));
        }
```

And the output is the correct one, i´ve thinking to have a counter and hardcoding with a case bucle and set the field deppending the counter, but the problem is that I have 40 fields...

Some idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: the problem is that i don´t want to harcode it, because if the class or the input string changes is a litle bit problem to repair it with 40 fields of the class

Comment: The use a `List` to put the items in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String line = "N001";"2014-08-12-07.11.37.352000";"         ";"some@email.com        ";4847       ;"street";"NAME        SURNAME                 ";26  ;"CALIFORNIA                      ";21  
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");

while(st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(st2.nextToken().replaceAll("\"",""));
}
```

Or you can use split method and directly get a array of values using the delimiter `;`

```
String []values = line.split(";");
```

then iterate through the array and get and cast the values they way you want

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the way you are parsing the file, you somehow need to define the mapping of column-to-field (and how to parse the text).

if this is a CVS file, you could use a library like super-csv. All you need to do is write a mapping definition.

Answer (score 0):

I would first split your input `String` based on the semi-colon separator, then clean up the values.

For instance:

```
String input = "\"N001\";\"2014-08-12-07.11.37.352000\";\"         " +
        "\";\"some@email.com        " +
        "\";4847       ;\"street\";\"NAME        " +
        "SURNAME                 \";26  ;\"CALIFORNIA                      " +
        "\";21  ";
// raw split
String[] split = input.split(";");
System.out.printf("Raw: %n%s%n", Arrays.toString(split));
// cleaning up whitespace and double quotes
ArrayList<String> cleanValues = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s: split) {
    String clean = s.replaceAll("[\\s\"]", "");
    if (!clean.isEmpty()) {
        cleanValues.add(clean);
    }
}
System.out.printf("Clean: %n%s%n", cleanValues);
```

**Output**

```
Raw: 
["N001", "2014-08-12-07.11.37.352000", "         ", "some@email.com        ", 4847       , "street", "NAME        SURNAME                 ", 26  , "CALIFORNIA                      ", 21  ]
Clean: 
[N001, 2014-08-12-07.11.37.352000, some@email.com, 4847, street, NAMESURNAME, 26, CALIFORNIA, 21]
```

**Note**

In order to map the values to your variables you will need to know their index in advance, and it will have to be consistent.

Then you can use the `get(int i)` method to retrieve them from your `List` - e.g. `cleanValues.get(2)` will get you the e-mail, etc.

**Note (2)**

If you do **not** know the indices in advance or they may vary, then you are in trouble. 
You can of course try to get those indices by using regular expressions but I suspect you might end up complicating your life quite a bit.

Comment: at the end i´ve to harcode it, but i like your idea of the List!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to automate your process.

Iterate over the fields

```
Field[] fields = dummyRow.getClass().getFields();
```

and set your values

```
SomeClass object =  construct.newInstance();
field.set(object , value);
```

Comment: wich is the type of dummyRow?
I´ve an String and a Class, called Mail.
'Mail mail = new Mail()
Field[] fields = mail.getClass().getFields();'
Is this ok?

Comment: yes it should have been SomeClass.class.getFields();